# List of uninstalled Programs

Tags: ubuntu-store

Anyone that uses Android/iOS will know that uninstalled apps will appear as a list in the Play Store/App Store. Is there a function like this on Ubuntu too? Logging in with an Ubuntu account does not help.

Comment: I have an samsung/android & crapple/ios device but wouldn't know how to do what you want on either (*thus not-everyone, or I can't conclude what you mean*).  From cli I can produce a list of all apps & libs/packages available in repos in Ubuntu, then exclude installed ones from that list - but can't imagine why I'd want to.  The list is too long & why would I want it?  Yes `aptitude` (package manager) provides a non-installed list of packages (by group) so why not use it?

Comment: If you go into play store, then my apps and games, then library, you will get a list of all apps ever installed. This does not include pre installed apps. The reason this is smart is, that if I get a new device, or reset my device, I would not have to search and remember everything I ever installed. It would all be in a list and I would just click install.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/17823/how-to-list-all-installed-packages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Ubuntu there's logs for both `apt` and `dpkg` in `/var/log` directory, so all action related to installing and uninstalling go there, however these logs are rotated ( i.e. archived and eventually deleted ). So in short, it's possible to generate a list of items you uninstalled from these logs with a few text processing utilities, but if you need a persistent list, you may want to disable log rotation as well. Beware that on Ubuntu app name and package to which app belongs may differ in format, i.e. something like difference between Firefox for Android and the actual .apk package name. The information in logs contains only package names.

Another thing to be aware of is that phones and tablets sync with cloud. Personal computer operating systems generally do not  do that unless configured by sysadmin at an organization. So there's no "list" in the Ubuntu software center as in Play store.